# Regex to get each outer struct in a serialized list of structs

Tags: regex, scala

Say I have a String which will always follow the format of `[{}]` and represents a list of struct objects which may contain inner structs (nesting can be unlimited here)

```
"[{key: val, key2: val}, {key: val, key2: val}, {key: val, key2: 
 {key3: val}}, {key: val}]"
```

is there a regex to obtain the outer structs in a list?

```
val allStructs:List[String] = 
[
  "{key: val, key2: val}",
  "{key: val, key2: val}",
  "{key: val, key2: { key3: val }}",
  "{key: val}"
]
```

I've tried `\{[^}]*\}.` but it includes the last closing square bracket

match 1 - `{key:val,key2:val}`,

match 2 - `{key:val,key2:val}`,

match 3 - `{key:val,key2:{key3:val}}`

match 4 - `{key:val}]`

Comment: I have no experience with Scala but `^  \{[\s\S]+?^  \}` might work: https://regex101.com/r/EbDP4W/1

Comment: If the nesting can be arbitrarily deep, then a regex is insufficient to solve this problem (I think it's a consequence of the pumping lemma, but I can't explain offhand why). Look into LR1 parsers, or more realistically just use an existing JSON parser, since it looks like you're dealing with JSON already.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It would have worked before OP's edit.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yep sorry about that, I wrote it that way for readability but didn't realize it would affect the actual regex.

Comment: I see, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work for your sample data:

```perl
(?:\{[^}]*)*\{[^{}]*\}(?:[^{]*\})*
```

Hopefully it's Scala compatible.

https://regex101.com/r/7dHyWb/1

Comment: I wasn't able to get this regex working with ```serializedList.split(regex).toList```, but ```regex.r.findAllIn(serializedList).toList``` actually works, thank you!

Comment: @user3613290 My experience with `.split()` methods is that you need to write the regex so that you're splitting on data which you wish to discard. My regex was difficult enough to conjure and `.split()` would require something quite different, if at all possible. Glad `.findAllIn()` worked!

Answer (score 2):

This allows for only one level of nesting, but then regex isn't the best tool for this type of parsing.

```
val str =
  "[{key: val, key2: val}, {key: val, key2: val}, {key: val, key2: {key3: val}}, {key: val}]"

raw"\{[^{}]*\{[^{}]*}[^{}]*}|\{[^{}]*}".r.findAllIn(str).toList
//res0: List[String] = List({key: val, key2: val}
//                        , {key: val, key2: val}
//                        , {key: val, key2: {key3: val}}
//                        , {key: val})
```